# PostAsync returning exception

Tags: c#, console-application, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using a Console App to do volume tests, in these tests I'm calling the JobTitles route that I created inside the API, in this case the controller that handles this route.

For the Post function, which I am using, I made use of the `HttpClient PostAsJsonAsync()` method. As I already used this function in other code I didn't have many problems, but now it is returning the exception `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.`

I'm not using any `.Result` call as it may end up causing a deadlock; I also tried using `.ConfigureAwait (false)` and it didn't work. I also tried to work with [Easy.Common RestClient()](https://github.com/NimaAra/Easy.Common/blob/master/Easy.Common/RestClient.cs) but the same error occurs, I'm running out of options for what the error might be. I'm sorry but I can't figure out what the error is just by looking at the stack trace,  I still didn't learn how figure it out.

I put the code here for better viewing as it is a little big:

https://repl.it/repls/JubilantMoccasinArrays

I tried to create a generic method since in the other code I made a Post for each Entity, taking advantage of the question, I would like to know if there is another one besides RestClient and HttpClient that I could use to send multiple calls without causing the shipments to be canceled due to many API entries, since it automatically cancels to avoid DDoS.

And the stack trace I get from RestClient:

```
Unhandled exception. System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: The response ended prematurely.
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.FillAsync()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ReadNextResponseHeaderLineAsync(Boolean foldedHeadersAllowed)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithNtConnectionAuthAsync(HttpConnection connection, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
at CodenApp.Studio2Me.VolumeTest.UsefulFunctions.HTTPFunctions`1.Post(String route, T content) in C:\Users\Yasmin Kruger\Documents\Studio2Me\Studio2Me\Tests\CodenApp.Studio2Me.VolumeTest\UsefulFunctions\HTTPFunctions.cs:line 29
   at CodenApp.Studio2Me.VolumeTest.Classes.JobTitleData.JobTitleDataGenerator(Int32 x) in C:\Users\Yasmin Kruger\Documents\Studio2Me\Studio2Me\Tests\CodenApp.Studio2Me.VolumeTest\Classes\JobTitleData.cs:line 21
   at CodenApp.Studio2Me.VolumeTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Yasmin Kruger\Documents\Studio2Me\Studio2Me\Tests\CodenApp.Studio2Me.VolumeTest\Program.cs:line 22
   at CodenApp.Studio2Me.VolumeTest.Program.<Main>(String[] args)
```

**EDIT1**:

I'm just sending one request just to test if it's working, I need to send at least x * 6 JobTitles without counting that there are more classes to send together, so I need a way that I can send a large amount of requests to the API.

**EDIT2**:

Stack Trace from HttpClient:

```
    System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: The response ended prematurely.
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.FillAsync()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ReadNextResponseHeaderLineAsync(Boolean foldedHeadersAllowed)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithNtConnectionAuthAsync(HttpConnection connection, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at CodenApp.Studio2Me.VolumeTest.UsefulFunctions.HTTPFunctions`1.PostTest(String route, T content) in C:\Users\Yasmin Kruger\Documents\Studio2Me\Studio2Me\Tests\CodenApp.Studio2Me.VolumeTest\UsefulFunctions\HTTPFunctions.cs:line 51
```

**EDIT3:**

Main.cs:

```
using System;
using CodenApp.Studio2Me.VolumeTest.Classes;
using CodenApp.Studio2Me.VolumeTest.UsefulFunctions;

namespace CodenApp.Studio2Me.VolumeTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)
        {
          // await JobTitleData.JobTitleDataGenerator(1);
          await JobTitleData.JobTitleDataGenerator2(1);
        }
    }
}
```

HTTPFunction.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Easy.Common.Extensions;
using Easy.Common.Interfaces;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Shouldly;
using RestClient = Easy.Common.RestClient;

namespace CodenApp.Studio2Me.VolumeTest.UsefulFunctions
{
    public class HTTPFunctions<T> where T : class
    {
        const string APIAddress = "http://localhost:5001/";

        public static async Task Post(string route, T content)
        {
            var endpointUri = new Uri(APIAddress + route);
            ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(endpointUri).ConnectionLeaseTimeout.ShouldBe(-1);

            var jsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content); 
            var contentString = new StringContent(jsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            contentString.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"); 

            using IRestClient client = new RestClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(endpointUri, contentString); //This won't work too
            //client.Timeout.ShouldBe(15.Seconds()); Sometimes cause an TimeOut Exception
            Console.WriteLine(response);
        }

        public static async Task PostTest(string route, T content)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(APIAddress);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                try
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(route, content).ConfigureAwait(false); //still not working            
                    if(!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(content);
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    //Using this just to get exception
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

JobTitleData.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Bogus;
using CodenApp.Studio2Me.Core.Entities.StoreEntities;
using CodenApp.Studio2Me.VolumeTest.UsefulFunctions;

namespace CodenApp.Studio2Me.VolumeTest.Classes
{
    public class JobTitleData
    {
        public static async Task JobTitleDataGenerator(int x)
        {
            var faker = new Faker("pt_BR");
            
            for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
            {
                JobTitle jobTitle = new JobTitle();
                jobTitle.Name = faker.Name.JobTitle();
                jobTitle.StoreId = 1;

                await HTTPFunctions<JobTitle>.Post("v1/Store/JobTitles", jobTitle);
            }
        }

        public static async Task JobTitleDataGenerator2(int x)
        {
            var faker = new Faker("pt_BR");
            
            for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
            {
                JobTitle jobTitle = new JobTitle();
                jobTitle.Name = faker.Name.JobTitle();
                jobTitle.StoreId = 1;

                await HTTPFunctions<JobTitle>.PostTest("v1/Store/JobTitles", jobTitle);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Several changes to the code were discussed with @Andy and the same returned the same error for me, I am doing the test on other machines and trying to call the same route through Insomnia to check if it is not something that has not been configured yet. For now it believes that it is the server preventing since I cannot return even an object response.

The changes proposed:

```
using (var msg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new UriBuilder(APIAddress) { Path = route }.Uri))
{
    msg.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            using (var resp = await _client.SendAsync(msg))
            {
                resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT4:**

After so much testing and using different programs to call the route, I noticed that it was really a server problem, more precisely the HTTP certification, because it is the one that is blocking the call. I will make changes to the project for more information and in edit5 I return what was decided and post an answer to finalize this question.

Comment: While you are waiting for some help, read though this: https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: @Andy I already saw that when I read about RestClient, but I need more then one request, I'm just sending one to test if my method is working, and I want to use RestClient because of it, i'm just using HttpClient because I'm more used to it

Comment: I just wanted you to tuck that in the back of your brain, that's all. I think I know what's wrong and will post an answer.

Comment: Can you post the exception from the HttpClient code. That is the error from using RestClient.

Comment: Please insert the code into the question.

Comment: @aepot https://repl.it/repls/JubilantMoccasinArrays <here

Comment: It doesn't work this way, the code must be inline because this question will be searched by many people while your source may be unsearchable/unavailable. SO is knowledge base and it must contain full information about the currently posted topic.

Comment: @aepot I made the edit to insert the code and showed the modification suggested by Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time I found out what the big problem was. Since I am using VSCode to program, I did not imagine that I should make any changes to the `.vscode` folder that was created as soon as the project was run locally. For those who are using and appear the error **Your connection is not private**, which is the same as **Not secure**, you must make the configuration, either from the file `launch.json` or `program.cs`, I made the modification directly on `launch.json`.

`launch.json` before modification:

```
{
    "name": ".NET Core Launch (api)",
    "type": "coreclr",
    "request": "launch",
    "preLaunchTask": "build",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Src/CodenApp.Studio2Me.Api/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/CodenApp.Studio2Me.Api.dll",
    "args": [],
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Src/CodenApp.Studio2Me.Api",
    "stopAtEntry": false,
    "serverReadyAction": {
        "action": "openExternally",
        "pattern": "^\\s*Now listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
    },
    "env": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
    },
    "sourceFileMap": {
        "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
    }
}
```

`launch.json` after modification:

```
{
    "name": ".NET Core Launch (api)",
    "type": "coreclr",
    "request": "launch",
    "preLaunchTask": "build",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Src/CodenApp.Studio2Me.Api/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/CodenApp.Studio2Me.Api.dll",
    "args": [],
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Src/CodenApp.Studio2Me.Api",
    "stopAtEntry": false,
    "serverReadyAction": {
        "action": "openExternally",
        "pattern": "^\\s*Now listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
    },
    "env": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "http://localhost:5001"
    },
    "sourceFileMap": {
        "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
    }
}
```

I just needed to add the line `"ASPNETCORE_URLS": "http://localhost:5001"` to remove the error of Not secure and the application ran correctly.

Answer (score 2):

So I believe your problem is on this line:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(route, 
    content).ConfigureAwait(false); //still not working            
if(!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    Console.WriteLine(content);
}
```

You haven't read anything yet. You just got the response object. You have to do this with that response:

```
var objectReturned = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<WhateverObject>();
```

or, to test:

```
var stringDataReturned = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

A typical scenario would look like this:

```
var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(route, content);
repsonse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

var data = await response.ReadAsStringAsync();
Console.WriteLine(data);
```

Comment: I don't need at all the response, I just need to Post the content. I called it just to view if something goes wrong. What is going wrong is that I don't even get the response Object, the application stops when it reach ```await client.PostAsJsonAsync(route,content)```. And I don't know what is causing it

Comment: @YasminKruger -- did you try using that code? You are doing that `using` on `HttpClient` which causes it to dispose before the request finishes, and, the `HttpResponseMessage` goes out of scope, which could also cause it. There are two parts to an Http request. The actual sending of data, and the actual receiving of data. You are only calling the sending, and then ignoring the recv.

Comment: Yes i tried, and this code is from another project that I already used it, I even ran the test on the other project again to check if something was wrong and it worked, but here it don't want to work either HttpClient() or RestClient(). I still intend to leave HttpClient aside to test RestClient, but as long as neither post works, I have nothing to do

Comment: @YasminKruger -- do you have encryption turned on in your server.

Comment: No, only Stag and prod is configured, but I'm using localhost, my machine don't use encryption

Comment: @YasminKruger -- well, i guess I will pull my answer. I have no idea why it is doing this. There is barely any information about that message you are getting, and the information that I do see is about the server failing, not the client. If you are using the code from my answer, and you are still getting that error, then it can only be the server screwing up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219363/discussion-between-yasmin-kruger-and-andy).